# Calculating confidence levels of a distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
data = [1,1,2,3,3,5,5]
point = 6
```

I do not know if this data is normal or anything else about its distribution. I would like to calculate with some confidence that `point` is significantly higher than the `data`.

I have tried:

```
import math
from scipy.stats import t
import numpy as np
confidence = (
    t.interval(0.95,len(data)-1,loc=np.mean(data),
    scale=np.std(data)/math.sqrt(len(data))))
```

This returns a lower and upper bound, but often when handling my actual data, the `point` I use appears to be significantly elevated, but is well below many of the numbers contained in `data`. Am I using the best test or is there something better?

Comment: Without some assumptions about the distribution, you will not get a meaningful confidence level. If you assume the data is normal, establish mu and sigma using data, and compute z = (point - mu) / sigma, then Q = erfc(|z|/sqrt(2)) is the probability of obtaining such a large outlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulae for confidence intervals can be find on wikipedia.  Assuming you know the formula, and assuming the data is normal, you can do something like...

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,1,2,3,3,5,5])
z_alpha = 1.96 #Change for appropriate alpha level.  I use standard normal, but you could use t-dist
n = data.size
m = data.mean()
s = data.std()
interval = m + z_alpha*s/np.sqrt(n)*np.array([-1,1])

# Point in interval?

point = 6

(point<=interval[1])&(point>=interval[0])
```